# Can't read and change original pg_hba.conf in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: networking, server, java, postgresql, aws

I can't to connect to aws remote ubuntu server where installed postgresql. And i want to connect from my pc to postgres on ubuntu i cant do that:

```
Unable to connect to server:
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

I know that i should add

```
host all all all md5
or
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
or
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

but when i want to open pg_hba.conf from Putty i do that `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf` i see empty list and down wrote "[new file]" but in `/etc/postgresql/12/main/` i see this file [/etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd6dt.png)

if i used `sudo sh -c 'echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'` i will create new file bg_hba.conf but owner will be root. 
Here is some detail:

```
$ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)
$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)
$ postgres -V
$ locate bin/postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -V
postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
$ /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
-bash: /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf: Permission denied
```

Please help me! 
In `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`
i have `listen_addresses = '*'`
I see that postgresql.conf have `rw-r--r--` and bg_hba.conf is `rw-r-----` i can't read this why and how i can change thad)

Comment: anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I have got the problem and it was a little error in my text path to `'bg_hba.conf' ->  'pg_hba.conf'` `/etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'` this change on this - > `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf'`